# This looks like spam

Tags: discussion

So - giving an answer - get told this looks like spam. It's not. How do we get this reviewed, put through or posted?

If there is no way to do this then I'll not be bothered answering again as why would I spend my time if it is not going to be allowed and can only find out after spending time.

Comment: What were you trying to post?

Comment: Hi Flugan, I don't think you have posted any answers under this account before - if you posted it under a different or unregistered account, we'll need your help finding it. Thanks!